# what if a shared library loaded twice?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

In my program, I created two threads. Each thread loads a dynamic library, say "libmylib.so". In libmylib.so, a global class object (`class A a`) is defined.

What will happen in this case? I see the class object (`A a`) is constructed twice. But are they the same object in memory? I am confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `std::cout << this << '\n';` in your class contstructor to see if the memory address is the same.

Comment: Global variables in a shared library is *usually* a bad idea.